# making a word in a sentence a number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to print a sentence out by replacing words with numbers. For example, "this is a test this is a test" would become "1234 1234".

This is what I have so far:

```
sentence_list = []
sentence = input('Input a sentence \n')
sentence_list.append(sentence)
print(sentence_list)
numbers = [val + '=' + str(i + 1) for i, val in enumerate(sentence.split())]
print(numbers)
```

However, I'm not sure how to go make it account for repeated words and for it to only print the numbers instead of "[word = 1]"

Comment: Do you understand your current code? What was the reason for choosing `enumerate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Same idea as Max, just a bit simpler.

```
SentenceList=[]
sentence=input('Input a sentence \n')

sentenceSplit = sentence.split(' ')

for word in sentenceSplit:
    if word not in SentenceList:
        SentenceList.append(word)
    print SentenceList.index(word) + 1,
```

Comment: Simpler, but much less efficient: lists have linear lookup time, dictionaries have constant lookup time.

Comment: This is also incorrect. "this is a test this is a test" will give "01230123" rather than the desired "12341234".

Answer (score 1):

I would solve this problem by looping through each word and checking if it has been encountered before, and if so, what its ID is. Based on your current code, you care about case, so my code will do the same.

```
out = []
data = {}
nextID = 1

for word in input('Input a sentence \n').split():
    tmp = "" # The current word will be stored here
    if word in data:
        tmp += str(data[word])
    else:
        data[word] = nextID
        nextID += 1
        tmp += str(data[word])
    out.append(tmp)
print(" ".join(out))
```

This puts a space between each number, because I wasn't sure where to put the space. In your example you put it in the middle - should it always put a space in the middle?

Also, if I hadn't put the spaces, then as soon as you get to 10 unique words there might be some ambiguity as to whether you mean `1` and `0` or `10`.

Answer (score 0):

```py
words_found = [] 

for word in input('Input a sentence \n').split():
    # Add each word to the list the first time it appears
    if word not in words_found:
        words_found.append(word)
    # Print the index in the last that the word appeared in
    print(words_found.index(word) + 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

[Max's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40953766/7246614) is great because it uses a dictionary for O(1) lookups. It can be made much simpler though

```py
data = {}

for word in input('Input a sentence \n').split():
    if word not in data:
        data[word] = len(data) + 1
    print(data[word])
```

or using [`dict.setdefault`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=built%20types#dict.setdefault)

```py
data = {}

for word in input('Input a sentence \n').split():
    print(data.setdefault(word, len(data) + 1))
```